# Swift | Why my UITableView is empty (customized cell)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

My tableview app looks like this:

[image: Empty tableview]

I don't know why that `label1` is not working.

Here's how I done this:

I dragged a `UITableViewController` and set it as initialViewController.

[image: Main.storyboard]

I set the UITableViewCell style as `Custom`

[image: UITableViewCell style]

Then I set that UITableViewController's `Custom Class`

[image: UITableViewController class]

and UITableViewCell's

[image: UITableViewCell class]

Then, I added some constraints:

[image: UITableViewCell label's constraints]

Here's `TableViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let arr = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1 // This should more than one if you want to see the sections and rows in your tableview
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("item", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.label1.text = arr[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

And here's `TableViewCell.swift`

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
}
```

Anyone knows how to solve this? I really need to use custom cell!

P.S. I'm using Xcode 7 beta 5, Swift 2.0

Comment: Did you add constraints for table view?

Comment: I use the `UITableViewController`, @anhtu, so it automatically added for me.

Comment: `override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 0
    }` is going wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```